# Nuget web.config.install.xdt not transforming

Tags: nuget, web.config-transform

I'm having problems figuring out how to transform the web.config file when my NuGet package it installed.  It's doing some of the transformations, but not all of them.

Here's the untouched web.config file that I need to modify upon installation of my NuGet package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />  ***** I want this removed *****
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />  ***** I want this removed *****
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here's what I want as the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcMailer.BaseURL" value="" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailFrom" value="info@email.net" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailSubject" value="Your Password has been reset." />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailTemplatePath" value="~/MailerTemplates/ResetPassword.html" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/SGAccount/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is transformed web.config file in the MVC application, which is incorrect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcMailer.BaseURL" value="" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailFrom" value="info@email.net" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailSubject" value="Your Password has been reset." />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailTemplatePath" value="~/MailerTemplates/ResetPassword.html" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />  ***** Not removed when it should be *****
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/SGAccount/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />  ***** Not removed when it should be *****
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is my web.config.install.xdt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(mode)" />
    <authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <forms loginUrl="~/SGAccount/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've read all the documentation on the Nuget.org site about how to use the XDT transformations, and it even works on this tester site; https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/, but it doesn't work in action.

I'm stumped.  Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Your transform as written does not seem to work in the webconfigtransformationtester site. It fails because the first locator is trying to match on the name attribute which does not exist. The first locator match should be `xdt:Locator="Match(mode)"`

Comment: @MattWard - you're right, I made a mistake with this example.  Otherwise it should work in the tester, but it still doesn't work when installing the Nuget package.

Comment: Your transform seems fine for me using NuGet 2.8.1 in Visual Studio.

Comment: @MattWard - hmmm.  I have NuGet 2.8.5 and only the inserts work, not the removes.  Well I have to think of something because I can't release this new version until I get this to work reliably.  I'm testing it from a localNugetfeed, is that how you are testing it?  BTW, thanks for the dialogue.

Comment: The NuGet version number has two parts: file version and product version. The plugin that I am using in Visual Studio 2013 is 2.8.50313.46 (file version) which corresponds to NuGet 2.8.1 (product version). I tested the transform by creating a NuGet package and adding it to a project from a package source that is pointing to a local directory.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I realized I needed to increment each nuspec version when I modified something in the package such as the XDT file.  I guess the nupkg file cannot be overwritten with a new version even in the local NuGet feed.  The newer versions of the packages did in fact show the correct results, although my final transformation file is a little different, but it does work now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the new web.config.install.xdt looks like that handled the job successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailFrom" value="info@email.net" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailSubject" value="Your Password has been reset." xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    <add key="SecurityGuardEmailTemplatePath" value="~/MailerTemplates/ResetPassword.html" xdt:Transform="Insert" />  
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/SGAccount/Login" timeout="2880" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" xdt:Transform="Remove" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Instead of trying to Remove the original authentication element, I changed the mode attribute, then I Inserted the forms element.  The rest seemed to work itself out once this worked correctly.